# Set the scrollable area size of WPF's scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I use `ScrollViewer` to be able to scroll the content inside the scrollviewer. Now I also need to be able to zoom the contents, and I use `RenderTransform` to scale up the contents, but the `ScrollViewer` doesn't recognize the scaled content (the scrollable area doesn't grow).

How can I manually calculate and the set the `ScrollViewer`'s scrollable area? Let's sat i'd like the scrollable area to be like 1000 x 1000 pixels, even when the content is only 100 x 100 pixels wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ScrollViewer to accommodate the scaled content, just set the content's LayoutTransform instead of its RenderTransform.  The key difference is that the effects of a LayoutTransform are taken into consideration during measure and arrange, and it sounds like that's exactly what you want.